# merge dataframe with multi-level column from a mapping

Tags: python, dataframe

```
A1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,0],'price':[1,9]},index= ['2000/01/01','2000/01/03'] )
A2 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,0], 'price':[3,6]}, index =  ['2000/01/02','2000/01/03'])

B1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,0],'price':[2,3]},index= ['2000/01/01','2000/01/03'] )
B2 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,0], 'price':[3,9]}, index =  ['2000/01/02','2000/01/03'])
  All_df =  pd.concat([A1, A2, B1,B2],axis=1,keys = ['A1','A2','B1','B2'])

All_df
              A1          A2          B1          B2      
           price value price value price value price value
2000/01/01   1.0   1.0   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0   NaN   NaN
2000/01/02   NaN   NaN   3.0   1.0   NaN   NaN   3.0   1.0
2000/01/03   9.0   0.0   6.0   0.0   3.0   0.0   9.0   0.0
```

I have a dataframe, All_df as above. 
Also have another dataframe AB

```
AB =  pd.DataFrame({ 'A':[6,3,3],'B':[3,2,1]},index =  ['2000/01/01','2001/01/02','2000/01/03'])
AB
                  A        B
2000/01/01        6        3
2001/01/02        3        2
2000/01/03        3        1
```

Also, i have a mapping dict.

```
mydict = {'A':['A1','A2'],'B':['B1','B2']}
```

The dict tells A1 and A2 are related to A, B1 and B2 are related to B.
According to this relationship, I would like to merge All_df and AB like below.

```
               A                      |  B
              A1          A2        A |  B1           B2         B
           price value price value  A |  price value price value B 
2000/01/01   1.0   1.0   NaN   NaN  6 |    2.0   1.0   NaN   NaN 3
2000/01/02   NaN   NaN   3.0   1.0  3 |    NaN   NaN   3.0   1.0 2
2000/01/03   9.0   0.0   6.0   0.0  3 |    3.0   0.0   9.0   0.0 1
```

How can i achieve this? Note the column name for A and B in the merged dataframe is not compulsory, it can be any string you want.

Comment: You want to achieve it only by mapping or it is fine by you if one arrives to the result you want in any way?

Comment: Hi, tollster. I would like have it by mapping because i have a number of data frames (likle A,B,C,D,E...). Doing it manually will be very time consuming